# Sum all entries in a SQL table column and show the sum in label on a form

Tags: c#, sql

I have built a form for inserting data into a SQL database. I have put a label on a form in which I want to show a sum calculation of a column in my database. I want to sum all data in column `Transaction` from my SQL database `KarticeM`.

My code is:

```
ammountlbl.tekst = Select sum(transaction) from karticeM;
```

Comment: looks like it's OK, you should add more details, remove the `dot` please. It's not clear what context is your code in.

Comment: What part do you have a question about? How to send the command "Select sum(transaction) from karticeM" to the database and retrieve the result?

Comment: @Peca : do you want to insert data from db to textbox?

Comment: Learn bit of basic first Peca

Comment: @Sudhakar no i want to sum all rows in coloum transaction, and put the resoult into label. You know allready how my database looks like :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database `karticeM` should be put in the connection string, not in the query. In the query, on the other hand, you need the table name, because SQL can't guess it for you.

```
SQLConnection dbConn = new SQLConnection("server=serverName,database=karticeM");
dbConn.Open();
SQLCommand query = new SQLCommand("SELECT SUM(Transaction) FROM whateverTableName");
query.Connection = dbConn;
Int sum = query.ExecuteScalar();
ammountlbl.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Looks like you spend more time completing this task, than OP did